# jquery animate on the container and then unbind the event

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-animate, unbind

Hi am trying to unbind an event after the animation is done and do not want to fire that event on that container . My approach

```
$('#container').on('mouseover.grow', function(){
    $(this).parents('.secondary').animate({height:'360'},1000);
}).off('mouseover.grow');
```

But this approach does not seems like working . Any pointer on what I am missing in here will be appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chaining the `.off()` method as you've done will result in it firing immediately.

You'll want to call it in the `complete` callback of the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method (i.e. wait until the animate is complete):

```
$('#container').on('mouseover.grow', function(){
    var $this = $(this); 

    $this.parents('.secondary').animate({height:'360'},1000, function() {
        $this.off('mouseover.grow');
    });
});
```

*Also note that we assign `var $this = $(this);` since the scope of `this` will be different in the callback function.*